# Issue in assigning dynamic ids to check boxes

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I tried the following code:

```
 <ui:repeat var="item" id="request" value="#{myBean.requestList}">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckBox id="#{item.name}" value="#{item.type}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

I also tried

```
 <ui:repeat var="item" id="request" value="#{myBean.requestList}">
        <ui:param name="dynamicVal" value="#{item.name}"/>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckBox id="#{dynamicValue}" value="#{item.type}"/>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
  </ui:repeat>
```

Both of these give an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: component identifier must not be a xero-length String at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isIdValid ..
```

Whats incorrect in this code? How can I assign dynamic id to the check box suhc that both the label & the id are same. I need this for automaton.

Comment: Why do you want a dynamic value for an `id` attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` attribute is evaluated during view build time, but the `<ui:repeat>` runs during view render time. Essentially, your IDs end up being `null` which is indeed invalid.

Just don't try to manually assign generate IDs. The `<ui:repeat>` will already automatically insert the current iteration index in the client ID. This example,

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <ui:repeat ...>
        <h:outputLabel for="checkboxId" ... />
        <h:selectBooleanCheckBox id="checkboxId" ... />
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

will end up like

```
<form id="formId">
     <label for="formId:0:checkboxId">...</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="formId:0:checkboxId" />
     <label for="formId:1:checkboxId">...</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="formId:1:checkboxId" />
     <label for="formId:2:checkboxId">...</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="formId:2:checkboxId" />
     ...
</form>
```

If you're absolutely positive that you need to manually fiddle with IDs like that, then use `<c:forEach>` instead. It runs during view build time, generating physically multiple JSF components. You can use `<c:forEach var>` and `varStatus` in the `id` attribute.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

---

By the way, have you considered `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` for the purpose?

Comment: I have a button. I need to update on few components after a response is returned. Ajax is not working as expected. The components which I expect to be updated are not getting updated. I have disbaled partial view state saving, still the view is not getting updated. How can this be handled?

Comment: You seem to have a new question. Just press `Ask Question` button to ask a new question instead of posting it as a comment on an answer to a different question.